# GObject: how to reset property to the default value?

Tags: gobject

I have a GObject which has a property of type GObject. I know that I can set this property like this:

```
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (my_object), "my-property", my_value_for_property, NULL);
```

But how do I reset the property to its default value? Probably, this line seems intuitive:

```
g_object_set_property (G_OBJECT (my_object), "my-property", NULL);
```

But what if I the default value ob "my-property" is non-null pointer to object? And anyway this line doesn't work. It seems I cannot just pass NULL to `g_object_set_property()`

Answer (score 5):

You need to get the `GParamSpec` for the property (essentially, the definition of the property on the class) using `g_object_class_find_property()`, then get its default value using `g_param_spec_get_default_value()`.

Something like the following should work:

```
GParamSpec *pspec = g_object_class_find_property (G_OBJECT_GET_CLASS (my_object), "my-property");
const GValue *default_value = g_param_spec_get_default_value (pspec);
g_object_set_property (my_object, "my-property", default_value);
```

Comment: gobject seems to be very user friendly :-)